# Is there a way to use color gradient for a line in Keynote?

Tags: keynote

I would like to have a line that has a gradient of colors in Keynote. Is that possible?

Comment: I don’t use keynote so I am hesitant to answer.  However, can’t you create a line (box) with a gradient fill in another application ([GraphicsMagick](https://graphicsmagick.org) is a free command line utility)and save it as a GIF or JPEG to be inserted into your keynote slide?

Comment: @Allan You should be able to create the line even in Keynote itself. All shapes (boxes, etc.) can be made editable. Just an awful lot of work, if the line looks like a brush stroke, which one of the predefined lines imitates.

Comment: I do not know how to make a "shape" into a "line" so I can edit it to be in gradient color.

Answer (score 0):

Create a rectangle and drag it to be a thin line, then follow the steps below.

For example, this is a 2pt rectangle with a gradient, and a regular 2pt line that's solid yellow.

[image: line vs rect comparison]

Click a shape or text box to select it, or select multiple objects.

In the Format sidebar, click the Style tab.

Choose one of the following:

- A color or gradient designed to go with the theme: Click the color
  well next to Fill, then choose a color or gradient.
- Any color: Click the disclosure arrow next to Fill, then click the Fill pop-up menu and choose Color Fill. Click the color wheel,
  then choose a color from one of the color palettes.
- A two-color gradient fill: Click the disclosure arrow next to Fill, click the Fill pop-up menu and choose Gradient Fill, then
  choose colors. The color well shows colors that match the theme; the
  color wheel opens the Colors window, where you can choose any color.
  Use the controls to change the angle and direction of the gradient.
- A custom gradient: Click the disclosure arrow next to Fill, click the Fill pop-up menu and choose Advanced Gradient Fill, then click the color stops below the slider to choose colors. Click the slider to add another color stop. You can drag the color stops and use the other controls to change the blend, angle, and direction of the gradient.

From: https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/fill-objects-with-color-or-an-image-tan754f55080/mac

Comment: Thanks, but that solution only works for a "shape", not a "line", or am I missing something?

Comment: @bobsacameno, yes, but a rectangle with a 2pt height is the same as a 2pt thick line. I'm testing in Keynote on iPad, but the format box allows you to set the width and height of a rectangle. In the attached photo it's 312pt and 2pt.

Comment: That's true for straight lines. I am actually interested in curvy lines. I was unclear in my original question.